# CSV - Processing each group of contiguous rows having the same values for certain fields

Tags: ruby

I have a large CSV file with the following headers: "sku", "year", "color", "price", "discount", "inventory", "published_on", "rate", "demographic" and "tags".

I would like to perform various calculations for each contiguous group of rows having the same values for "sku", "year" and "color". I will refer to this partition of the file as each *group of rows*. For example, if the file looked like this:

```
sku,year,color,price,discount,...
100,2019,white,24.61,2.3,...
100,2019,white,29.11,2.1,...
100,2019,white,33.48,2.9,...
100,2019,black,58.12,1.3,...
200,2018,brown,44.15,3.1,...
200,2018,brown,53.07,3.2,...
100,2019,white,16.91,2.9,...
```

there would be four groups of rows: rows 1, 2 and 3 (after the header row), row 4 alone, rows 5 and 6 and row 7 alone. Notice that the last row is not included in the first group even though it has the same values for the first three fields. That it is because it is not contiguous with the first group.

An example of a calculation that might be performed for each group of rows would be to determine the total inventory for the group. In general, the measure to be computed is some function of the values contained in all the rows of the group of rows. The specific calculations for each group of rows is not central to my question. Let us simply assume that each group of rows is passed to some method which returns the measure of interest.

I wish to return an array containing one element per group of rows, each element (perhaps an array or hash) containing the common values of "sku", "year" and "color" and the calculated measure of interest.

Because the file is large it must be read line-by-line, rather than gulping it into an array.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I dont know how much this link help you.  please let me. know if it helps  https://github.com/learnbyexample/Command-line-text-processing/blob/master/ruby_one_liners.md

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. We'd like to know what you tried. Currently it doesn't look like you did.

Comment: Thanks, @theTinMan for your comment. I will definitly look at them.

Comment: Sig, I trust you don't mind my edit. It's an interesting question so I would like to see it reopened. @Amadan, please consider voting to reopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Enumerator#chunk` is perfect for this.

```
CSV.foreach('path/to/csv', headers: true).
  chunk { |row| row.values_at('sku', 'year', 'color') }.
  each do |(sku, year, color), rows|
    # process `rows` with the current `[sku, year, color]` combination
  end
```

Obviously, that last `each` can be replaced by `map` or `flat_map`, as needed.

Comment: Yes, this is the way to do it. I considered `chunk` but concluded, incorrectly, that I would be producing a big array. Why `lazy`, assuming you are reading the entire file?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: You are right, it seems `chunk` returns an enumerator. Go figure. There's very few parts of Ruby I dislike; the inconsistency when you get an enumerator and when you get an array is one. I used `lazy` because I, too, thought `Enumerator#chunk` produces an array (and expected `Enumerator::Lazy#chunk` to produce an enumerator, as it does).

Comment: One that bugs me is [Array#product](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-product), which I would expect to return an enumerator (as does `combination`, `permutation`, etc.), but it returns an array.

Comment: @Amadan thanks for your reply. Indeed `Enumerator#chunk` seems a good candidate for the job. However, as far as I understand from the docs, it loops through the entire file loading it. Right?

Comment: Of course it loops the entire file, or you wouldn't be able to get any results. But it yields to the block each time a chunk is detected, and does not save rows to memory except the current chunk. This is different from `#group_by`, which needs the entire array in memory before it produces anything (and then it produces _everything_).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So, since we can assume the CSV is ordered. `Enumerator#chunk` should loop only once or will it loop n times (where n is the number of chuncks). Again, thank you.

Comment: If the file was not ordered, `#chunk` gives you only the adjacent lines with the same key; so you would get many more chunks than when the same file was ordered. `#group_by` would find all the rows with the same key. This is why `#chunk` can do it on the fly, but `#group_by` needs to see everything.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how that might be done. I will read the CSV file line-by-line to minimize memory requirements.

**Code**

```
require 'csv'

def doit(fname, common_headers)
  CSV.foreach(fname, headers: true).
      slice_when { |csv1,csv2| csv1.values_at(*common_headers) !=
        csv2.values_at(*common_headers) }.
      each_with_object({}) { |arr,h|
        h[arr.first.to_h.slice(*common_headers)] = calc(arr) }
end
```

```
def calc(arr)
  arr.sum { |csv| csv['price'].to_f }.fdiv(arr.size).round(2)
end
```

The method `calc` needs to be customized for the application. Here I am computing the average price for each contiguous group of records having the same values for `"sku"`, `"year"` and `"color"`.

See [CSV::foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach), [Enumerable#slice_when](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when), [CSV::Row#values_at](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html#method-i-values_at), [CSV::Row#to_h](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html#method-i-to_h) and [Hash#slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-slice).

**Example**

Now let's construct a CSV file.

```
str =<<~END
sku,year,color,price
1,2015,red,22.41
1,2015,red,33.61
1,2015,red,12.15
1,2015,blue,36.18
2,2015,yellow,9.08
2,2015,yellow,13.71
END

fname = 't.csv'
File.write(fname, str)
  #=> 129
```

The common headers must be given:

```
common_headers = ['sku', 'year', 'color']
```

The average prices are obtained by executing `doit`:

```
doit(fname, common_headers)
  #=> {{"sku"=>"1", "year"=>"2015", "color"=>"red"}=>22.72,
  #    {"sku"=>"1", "year"=>"2015", "color"=>"blue"}=>36.18,
  #    {"sku"=>"2", "year"=>"2015", "color"=>"yellow"}=>11.4}
```

Note:

```
((22.41 + 33.61 + 12.15)/3).round(2)
  #=> 22.72
((36.18)/1).round(2)
  #=> 36.18 
((9.08 + 13.71)/2).round(2)
  #=> 11.4
```

The methods `foreach` and `slice_when` both return enumerators. Therefore, for each contiguous block of lines from the file having the same values for the keys in `common_headers`, memory is acquired, calculations are performed for those lines and then that memory is released (by Ruby). In addition, memory is needed to hold the hash that is returned at the end.